# Connection to SQL Server database doesn't work online

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio, web-config

I have a project in Visual Studio, which I have connected to my SQL Server database.

When I try it locally in the program, I get a website with the actual data, which is in my database.

But when I publish the same project and insert those files in the folder of my .NET instance (web server). I will get the website, where I can see all the result of html code etc, but there's no connection to my database.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="xxx" 
         connectionString="server=<serverlink>;database=DB_xxx_SQL;Persist Security Info=True;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx" />
    <add name="zzz" 
         connectionString="server=<serverlink>;database=DB_xxx_SQL;Persist Security Info=True;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I think you need to install SQL Express where the application running, let SQL Engine host your database files which can be accessible via connection string

Comment: Where do you publish the project too? It sounds like the server you are publishing too doesn't have access to the database server.

Comment: I'm publishing it to a .NET instance of a WebServer.

Answer (score 0):

Try connection strings by removing **Persist Security Info=True;**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="xxx" 
         connectionString="server=<serverlink>;database=DB_xxx_SQL;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx" />
    <add name="zzz" 
         connectionString="server=<serverlink>;database=DB_xxx_SQL;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The configuration and the access to the Connection string looks all right to me. I would always add a providername**

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="xxx" 
       connectionString="Data Source=yourservername;Initial Catalog=yourdatabasename;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  />
</connectionStrings>
```